# Displaying multiple activities on same screen

Tags: android

TabHost has a great method setContent where I can set another Activity, so I will have two active activities:TabActivity and activity that I will set in setContent.

Is there any possibility to do that without TabHost ? Just one activity with view where I can set another activity.

**P.S. Fragments not work for me !!!**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

no, I'm afraid beside TabHost or using fragments, it's not possible to do that. actually, without tabHost - I don't understand why such a thing would be usefull to you.  because switching between activities without tab - is trivial..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display different views in the same activity, it is possible through ViewGroup. It is **not** different Activity, but it can suit your needs. You can check it, if you run the ApiDemos - go to Views->Animation->3D Transition.